# Prettier ignore handlebars

Tags: javascript, prettier

I have the following folder structure in my Meteor project.

```
> .meteor

>public

> client (dir)
>> foo.html &
>> foo.js

>> bar (dir: client/bar)
>>> bar.html &
>>> bar.js

> server
>> baz.js
```

I want to format all JS files inside of client directory

npx prettier --write 'client/**/*.js'

only formats files like bar.js. In reality I have up to 5 levels deep folders, and they need to be formatted too.

npx prettier --write 'client/**'

Works, but affects html (handlebar) files, I want to avoid that.

Any ideas? I can't find anything in the documentation, a part from manually adding an ignore to all .html files but that's an overkill.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the following config to avoid handlebars (.hbs) formatting

```js
"[handlebars]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": false,
    "editor.formatOnPaste": false
}
```

Comment: It’s being executed from a command line, unfortunately circleci will have no clue about editor.formatOnSave

Comment: You should've mentioned that you're using in circleci. Also, you have to disable prettier in ci builds

Answer (score 4):

Add a `.prettierignore` file to your project root to ignore handlebars files, e. g.:

```
*.handlebars
```